# Compositing glare, without affecting other emmision materials

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

As you can see in the image, I am adding glare effects to the emissions off the engines. But its also affecting the white emission material as well on the upper sensor node above the engines. How can i separate the glare to only affect the engines and not all other glow on the ship?

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](https://i.gyazo.com/af9f8e621fa42cc5a62d9de89aafa28e.png))</sub>

=================================================================================

So after re aranging and piping the material though the mask with passes setup. it works kinda.... but as u can see the effect is rather gone now from what it was.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](https://i.gyazo.com/924e71bb11f6cfb0b88da0180ee68062.png))</sub>

===============================

Thank you all for your help. but i managed to fix it by putting the Eng's into a separate layer. so the hull layer 1 and eng's layer 2 and rendering it that way.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](https://i.gyazo.com/e0aac54fda6ec746f1fb595d4ff89312.png))</sub>

thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [One part of the render layer glowing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing/35860#35860)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35414/compositor-id-mask-not-working/35448#35448 and [Able to mask out the eye but the glowing part of it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36065/able-to-mask-out-the-eye-but-the-glowing-part-of-it/36068#36068)

Comment: Or you can play with the brightness levels, so that only the emissions that reach a certain value use the glare. That is what the threshold option is for on the glare node. Read: [control light halos based on emission level](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/any-way-to-control-light-halos-in-the-compositor-based-on-emission-level/54173#54173)

Comment: Is it possible to seprate the blue glowing emission layer from the white glow emission layer with Render passes? idk XD

Comment: Look also here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88613/problem-with-id-mask-and-glow-effect/88662#88662 and maybe here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88584/creating-a-planet-atmosphere-blurry-edge/88602#88602

Comment: @sora please don't answer the question as part of the text in the original post. Write an answer in the answers section and mark it  as accepted. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. I